# Proper Email Salutations to a group

Tags: email, nuance, salutations

Is it inappropriate to use the salutation "Ladies" when referring to a group 5 women in an email?  I was told the term could be offensive to women. Is this true?

I usually use the term "Folks" when emailing mixed gender audience, but will use "Gentlemen" (if all men, or informal "Guys" if I know everyone).  I didn't think the use of "Ladies" was an offensive term.

Comment: You completely omitted the context.  Is this a lady's church group or a group of coworkers who all are coincidentally female?  This is incredibly important.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of acknowledging their genders, you could say "Dear Colleagues" or simply "Greetings". Names work too, for small groups. For example, "Dear Devin, Bill, John, and Amanda". Using the "dear" title is the preferred salutation in email communication.

Comment: The question is about whether using "ladies" would be offensive to women or not. Please answer the question.

Comment: Some women dislike the label ladies. They think of themselves as women, men's equal. So yes, in this sense, it would be offensive.

Comment: Please edit your answer as a comment box is not for answering a question. .